# Owl carousel responsive navigation arrows size change

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I have an owl carousel with cards in my project. It's my first time using it. I've set up to be one card in viewport while screen is small but the arrows are still too big and not fitting the screen nicely. Is there any possibility to change that? sorry for asking but as I wrote earlier I'm just learning all the web dev stuff.

Comment: Note that this question doesn't relate to [tag:owl], but to [tag:owl-carousel] or [tag:owl-carousel-2].  I'm not sure which of the latter two is appropriate, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this thing is in your css.. reducing the font size would change the size of the arrows

```css
.owl-nav i {
  font-size: 52px;
}
```